# Why my jQuery function getJSON is not calling my function callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#EstadoId").change(function(){
            listaCidade($(this).val());
        });
    });

    function listaCidade(uf) {
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("ListaCidade")/" + uf, listaCidadeCallBack);
    }

    function listaCidadeCallBack() {
        alert('sucesso');
    }
```

Everything is working...getJSON is calling my action "ListaCidade" but it isnt calling my "listaCidadeCallBack".

The result of the Action is

```
 public ActionResult ListaCidade(int id)
        {
            var cidades = from c in ctx.Cidades
                          where c.Estado.ID == id
                          select c;

            return Json(cidades);
        }
```

Comment: What's the result from the Action?

Comment: I edited the post with the ActionResult

Comment: Are you sure the request was successful? That callback should only fire if the result returns a success/200.

Comment: If the request failed or an invalid response was returned, your callback wouldn't be called. So make sure that the request succeeds and the response is valid.

Comment: Your quotes are off, resulting in improper string concatenation. Are you sure your getJSON is being called properly? Check the network tab.

Comment: the action result is returning what I want...

Comment: @SterlingArcher: `@Url.Action("ListaCidade")` is likely replaced by the server side code.

Comment: @FelixKling ah. Nevermind then.

Comment: For debugging, you could also try the following bit, this is using the Deferred returned to access the success and failed `$.getJSON("@Url.Action("ListaCidade")/" + uf).done(listaCidadeCallBack).fail(function(){alert('failed');});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be you might not be getting the expected result from the api call.

Add the `fail` event to the `getJSON` call and that will tell you what is wrong.

```
 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("ListaCidade")/" + uf, listaCidadeCallBack)
 .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
      console.log(error);
      var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
      alert("Request Failed: " + err );
 });
```

**EDIT** : *As per the comment*, your GET action method has trouble sending JSON data.

Solution is, You need to pass `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as the second paramenter of Json method, when your action method is of `GET` type.

```
public ActionResult ListaCidade()
{
   var cidades = from c in ctx.Cidades
                          where c.Estado.ID == id
                          select c;
    return Json(cidades , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

for `HttpPost` action method, You can use your old code without this second parameter.

Comment: @Daniel: So there is something wrong with the request / response. The `fail` callback gets passed information about the error. Look at that and/or look at the request in the network tab.

Comment: @Daniel See my updated answer which alerts the error detail

Comment: @Daniel As Felix mentioned in his comment, Open up network tab and see whether you are getting a 404 /500 or 200 response. Since it is a GET call, you can open that url in a new browser tab/window and see why it is failing.

Comment: @Shyju now I got "Request Failed: error, Internal Server Error"

Comment: @Daniel So your second action method is failing. You have some code error you need to fix. Try to access the URL (to ListaCidade) in a new browser window to see the error.

Comment: Accessing the URL I got something like this To permit  GET...configure JSonRequestBehavior as AllowGet.

Comment: I just add a parameter in the return of my actionResult "return Json(cidades,JSonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)" and know it worked...the callback function was called lol

Comment: yes like u did in the updated answer...thank you bro !